# Modify VIEWS query without custom module

Tags: 7, views, database, css-js-aggregation

I have to do a very simple thing but I'm not good at writing modules. Here is the the query that VIEWS generates

`SELECT users.name AS users_name, users.uid AS uid, node_users__field_data_field_mine.field_mine_value AS node_users__field_data_field_punch_start_field_mine_v`

and I need this to become

`SELECT users.name AS users_name, users.uid AS uid,DATE(node_users__field_data_field_mine.field_mine_value)AS node_users__field_data_field_punch_start_field_mine_v`m

Any advices are welcommed.